# CLLocationManager.location is nil

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

this is my locationManager init method:

```
func initLocationManager() {
        seenError = false
        locationFixAchieved = false
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()     
}
```

after calling this method this line

```
println(self.locationManager.location)
```

prints nil
why is that? it worked for me well at the past i just made few changes in my app and it doesn't work well now..

Comment: Where are you printing the location?  In the delegate method?  Have you disallowed location for your app in privacy settings?

Comment: unfortunately i didn't find those privacy settings you talk about, can you please be more specified?

Comment: Settings application ->Privacy->Location Services->Your app name

Comment: okay i checked this out and it's allowed, while i still get nil.. another solution?

Comment: Ok, so the second part of my question - where are you printing the location?  You shouldn't attempt to access the location until the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method is called

Answer (score 17):

1) [CLLocation location documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location)
- The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.

2) You've set the delegate for CLLocationManager. Why not implement [locationManager:didUpdateLocations:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:) and print the latest retrieved location from inside?

3) Are you using a simulator or a real device? Bear in mind that if you are using a simulator you may need to enable simulate location:

[image: Xcode location]
[image: Dropdown]

You can also find a `Custom Location` option in:
- `Simulator -> Debug -> Location -> Custom Location...`

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 8 `requestAlwaysAuthorization` is ignored if you do not provide a string for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your Info.plist.

[Link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18)