# startUpdatingLocation returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use CLLocation. Every time I try to call the method startUpdatingLocation(), the values of of the current latitude and longitude are always nil. I included `locationManager.delegate = self` and `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` in the `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
func findCurrentLocation() -> String{
    // GET LOCATION OF USER
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    })

    var lat = String(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
    var long = String(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)

    var ll = lat + "," + long
    return ll
}
```

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093422/cllocationmanager-location-is-nil ?

Comment: where you called this method `findCurrentLocation`

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the location straight away. You need to wait until the callback your `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

If you are targeting iOS 9 you can call `requestLocation` for a one-shot location update but it still,comes via `didUpdateLocations`