# Get current latitude and longitude in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

I have an application that shows me information on restaurants by longitude and latitude. How can I get the current location and place it in the URL? The idea is that I search by that location, not by a given coordinate.

```
class Observer: ObservableObject {

@Published var  datas = [Datatype]()


init() {

    let url1 = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=\(latitude)8&lon=\(longitude)"
    let key = "c913841060ea614f7c0f5b5f120a21cb"
    //latitude = 33.4592298 - longitude = -70.645348

    print(url1)

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a Swift UI question and more of a general Swift question. You can use `CLLocationManager` to get the user's current location. Be sure to import `CoreLocation` first.

```swift
import CoreLocation

...

init() {
    let latitude = CLLocationManager().location?.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = CLLocationManager().location?.coordinate.longitude
    let url1 = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=\(latitude ?? 0.0)8&lon=\(longitude ?? 0.0)"
    let key = "c913841060ea614f7c0f5b5f120a21cb"
    //latitude = 33.4592298 - longitude = -70.645348

    print(url1)

  ...
}
```

You will also have to make sure you get the user's permission to access their location. This requires setting `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your info.plist with a string value that explains how you are using the user's location. You can request access via `CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. You can check the location authorization status via `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()`.

Comment: Does not work, latitude and longitude at the output is 0.0:
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=0.08&lon=0.0

Comment: Are you on a simulator? You will have to enable "simulate location" to actually get a location. 0.0 is returned because `CLLocationManager().location` is returning nil, so it is defaulting lat and lng to 0.0. Make sure you also perform the steps in the last paragraph of my answer. You have to get permission from the user before you can grab their location.

Comment: Check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093422/cllocationmanager-location-is-nil these may be some issues as to why `CLLocationManager().location` is returning `nil`. You need to be sure to provide the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your info.plist.

Comment: In the info.plist:

Privacy - Location When In Use Description

Done. Above the authorization is also declared. But still doesn't work :(

Comment: Is simulate location turned on on your simulator? If you can diagnose why `CLLocationManager().location` is returning `nil`, you should be golden.

Comment: The location in the simulator is On.